# Is Python's shutil.rmtree() a blocking call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When we use Python's `shutil.rmtree()`, does the OS make sure that the folder is deleted (blocking call) before next instruction is executed?

Comment: You can find the source code here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/shutil.py

Comment: It's hard to imagine how else it would work. A brief experiment with a large directory tree should remove any doubt.